# In C++, is it possible to easily sort a vector of object type pointers, with respect to any attribute of those objects?

Tags: c++, sorting, attributes, vector

Is it possible to easily sort a vector of object type pointers, with respect to any attribute of those objects?

Let's say `students` is the vector of object type pointers, when the object `student` are type of `Student` and has two methods `student.studentAlias()` and `student.studentName()`. How can I sort the vector with respect to the aliases?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This thread describes a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085231/c-select-argmax-over-vector-of-classes-w-r-t-arbitrary-expression/5085323#5085323

Answer (score 13):

You can use a functor:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class StudentAliasComparator
{
public:
    bool operator()(const Student* left, const Student* right) const
    {
        return left->studentAlias() < right->studentAlias();
    }
};

void SortVectorOfStudentByAlias(std::vector<Student*>& students)
{
    std::sort(students.begin(), students.end(), StudentAliasComparator());
}
```

You could also use lambda either from boost, or from the langage (if you use C++0x). With C++0x syntax, it would be something like (can't check as I don't have access to a C++ compiler that supports C++0x right now):

```
void SortVectorOfStudentByAlias(std::vector<Student*>& students)
{
    std::sort(students.begin(), students.end(),
        [](const Student* l, const Student* r) {
            return l->studentAlias() < r->studentAlias(); })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can sort with the std::sort algorithm:

```
template <class RandomAccessIterator, class StrictWeakOrdering>
void sort(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, StrictWeakOrdering comp);
```

Simply supply a function object (comp) that performs a less than compare for the attribute you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::mem_fun`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/mem_fun/) and a wrapper:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <typename F>
struct CompareBy
{
    bool operator()(const typename F::argument_type& x,
                    const typename F::argument_type& y)
    { return f(x) < f(y); }

    CompareBy(const F& f) : f(f) {}

 private:
    F f;
};

template <typename F>
CompareBy<F> by(const F& f) { return CompareBy<F>(f); }
```

and to sort, do

```
std::vector<Student*> students;

std::sort(students.begin(), students.end(), 
          by(std::mem_fun(&Student::studentAlias))
);
```

If you want to sort by member variables, there is unfortunately no `std::mem_ptr`. Use the ideas from my answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085231/c-select-argmax-over-vector-of-classes-w-r-t-arbitrary-expression/5085323#5085323) to build your own.